# ReactiveCoca Design Pattern for Forwarding / Chaining Signals

Tags: ios, objective-c, functional-programming, reactive-cocoa

I have the following classes and methods:

Class A

```
- (RACSignal *)createX
{
    NSDictionary *parameters = @{};

    return [[[[HTTPClient sharedClient] rac_POST:@"X/" parameters:parameters]
        map:^id(OVCResponse *response) {
            [self logResponse:response];
            return response.result;
        }] catch:^RACSignal *(NSError *error) {
        return [RACSignal error:[self handleError:error]];
    }];
}
```

Class B

```
- (void)requestData
{
    [[self.myClassA createX]
     subscribeNext:^(NSArray *results) {
        DDLogDebug(@"response : %@", results);
    }
     error:^(NSError *error) {
            [self.dataManager sendError:error];
        }];
}
```

Class C

```
- (void)retrieveData
{
    [self.myClassB requestData];

}
```

What is the best way to design `requestData` in `Class B` such that the `results` array can be accessed in `Class C`.

**i.e.**

Should I forward the Array some way using `[array rac_sequence]`, 
should I create a new signal inside requestData, should `requestData` return a `RACSignal` instead of `void`?

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I am not familiar with reactive-cocoa, but you should probably add a block parameter to the retrieveData method, that is called when the results are available. Class C can then specify what it wants to do with the results.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want to use `doNext` instead of `subscribeNext` in Class B.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely clear on your use case here but I think you are mixing paradigms.  RAC stuff is always asynchronous so in order to access the result of your network request synchronously you will have to store it in some way.

You could bind the result to a property on ClassB or you could use `RACCommand`, something like:

```
[[RACCommand alloc] initWithEnabled:RACObserve(self, valid) signalBlock:^RACSignal *(id input) {
return [[RACSignal createSignal:^RACDisposable *(id<RACSubscriber> subscriber) {

    //make network call

    //send responseObject to subscriber
    [subscriber sendNext:responseObject];
    //[subscriber sendError:#NSError#] //send error if something went wrong
    [subscriber sendCompleted];
    return nil;
}] materialize];
}];
```

You can then subscribe to the `executionSignals` of the `RACCommand` which streams a `RACSignal` for each execution of the command which you have control over in the block described above.

So I think your options are:

- `RACCommand` pattern, look into it a bit more
- Bind result of network call to a property for synchronous access
- Return a `RACSignal` as you describe upon calling the method
- Possibly look into `replay()` or `replayLast()` [here](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/06/29/replay-replaylast-replaylazily/) as you could then store a reference to the `RACSignal` and subscribe to it for access to its last value